# Why Linked list called linked list Why not linked items?

Tags: arrays, arraylist, linked-list, dynamic-arrays

If im mistaken or misunderstood in linked items the first `item` in `memory` points to the `address` of the `next element` then it should be called `linked items/linked pointers` right, Please correct me if it's wrong i'm ready to learn, and `List` is complete different from linked list isn't,`lists` are arrays with `prebooked addresses/placeholders` or it's just `arraylist`.

Comment: I'm not one of the creators of the Java language, but I suspect a LinkedList is called a LinkedList because it implements the List interface using links.

Comment: It implements list interface but it's not exactly list as well right it points to the other ithem from the previous item in the list right.

Comment: Definition of [list](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/list)